# search songs by bpm range and key using spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

On spotipy's docs I can see that the only way it seems to be possible to search songs is by artist's name or title.

```
results = sp.search(q='weezer', limit=20)
for idx, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
    print(idx, track['name'])
```

Is there any way to search by BPM,KEY and GENRE all togheter?

Comment: As far as I know they haven't introduced a way to search by bpm: [discussion](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Social/How-do-you-search-by-BPM/td-p/833465)
However, with genre, I did find this [article](https://dev.to/ericbonfadini/finding-my-new-favorite-song-on-spotify-4lgc) what searches similar songs, so kind of searching genre.

Comment: there is this endpoint `https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations` which gives you the possibility to do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is! The endpoint `https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations` lets you get songs based on BPM, key and genre (and much more). You can provide Spotify with a `target_key`, `target_tempo` and up to 5 genres under `seed_genres`. Spotify then returns songs that fit the given parameters.